# Docker pull error: error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I installed docker to my ubuntu 20.04. At the beginning I was able to pull images without an issue. Later I don't remember what change I did(I played a lot with resolv.conf), now I can't pull.

I can login with CLI successfully, but pulling gives me error like this:

```
error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Here is /etc/resolv.conf

```
aman@aman-Latitude-3420:~$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

daemon.json

```
aman@aman-Latitude-3420:~$ sudo cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{

    "mtu":1300
}
```

My docker version on Ubuntu 20.04 :

```
aman@aman-Latitude-3420:~$ sudo docker --version
Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414
```

docker info

```
aman@aman-Latitude-3420:~$ sudo docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.5.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.16
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
 runc version: v1.1.1-0-g52de29d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.14.0-1036-oem
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.516GiB
 Name: aman-Latitude-3420
 ID: TU5Z:OVST:TUKD:NI5U:4PVI:RYRL:V3R7:PYFZ:JAJW:MRFX:PDT6:WU7M
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.0/8,::1,registry-1.docker.io,registry-1.docker.io,*
 Username: amanmyrat
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

What I did so far:

1. I tried with vpn as well.
2. I edited resolv.conf accordingly with
   proxy addresses. but the result is same.
3. I edited daemon.json, according to some stackoverflow answers. I
   reloaded deamon and  restarted docker every time I changed any
   setting.
4. I uninstall docker, and installed again.
5. I reset my ubuntu to factory defaults,I mean reinstalled ubuntu then installed docker.

In my opinion I cannot pull because of my low internet connection(as some stackoverflow answers suggest). My speed is max 2mb/s. But How can this be solved?

Any help of yours is appreciated, thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/908141/docker-pull-tls-handshake-timeout) please, it seems the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconfigure your `/etc/resolv.conf`.

[Article to help to do that](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by open cloudflare.com website in my browser and check human detection after that again run docker compose

Comment: Provide some source and results which proves that you've solved